# Updating record after commiting changes?

Tags: ember.js

I have a form that edits a single record. I commit the change using `record.get('transaction').commit();` and it all goes swell - it is correctly stored, no errors occur and it is marked as "not dirty". But further inspection reveals that the record is not updated with committed data! Refreshing reloads it and then it is ok, but shouldn't ember automatically refresh the record in question after it gets response for PUT in format {'objects': [new record data is here]} ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PUT response should have the updated record in `{object: {field: value}}` not `objects`